# How to send sms messages to be detected in iOS application

Tags: ios, sms, nsnotification

I want to be able to open my application or receive a notification when the app receives a text from a specific number.

For example, I want my application to check for this number: 301-212-1312
and every time a text from this number comes to my phone, i want the app to create a notification or open. And upon opening, it parses the information in the text and searches for a html or web link. That link is then displayed in a label to the user in the application.

Sample Text from 301-212-1312:

Hey can you help me with my code, I even tried searching for solutions on www.stackoverflow.com

Sample Application action:

Application opens, parses text from number and displays only the web link

Click here to go to page: www.stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do this the way you want to. Apps in iOS are sandboxed, so they live in their own bubble and don't have access to other system events such as receiving a text from a certain number. Instead, what you would have to do is create a specific link that your app can open, and have that link deep link to your app (which is new as of iOS 9) be sent in your message. Think getting a message from someone that sent you from Floorboard, where you click on the link and it takes you to that story in the app, rather than their website.

Comment: Deep linking is not an iOS feature at all.  Any app can do it, on any iOS version.

Comment: Any app has been able to do this, but it required opening the link, opening the app store, and then confirming that you wanted to open the specific app. As of iOS 9, with the new `CoreSpotlight.framework` deep linking has changed to allow it so that links go directly to the app in question, which is more like OP was asking about. "Core Spotlight framework provides APIs that help you add app-specific content to the on-device index and **enable deep links into your app.**" https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS9.html

Comment: Strange... so I guess the deep linking that my app does on iOS 7 that opens the app without a prompt (except on iOS 9, ironically enough) and performs a specific action (could just as easily go to a specific view) automatically is all a figment of my imagination?

Comment: Keep in mind that the question implicitly states that the app is already installed.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to [XMPP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMPP) protocol, you can find some implementation from [github](https://github.com/search?l=Objective-C&q=xmpp&type=Repositories&utf8=%E2%9C%93)

A definition from wikipedia

> Extensible Messaging and Presence Protocol (XMPP) is a communications
>   protocol for message-oriented middleware based on XML (Extensible
>   Markup Language).[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMPP) It enables the near-real-time exchange of
>   structured yet extensible data between any two or more network
>   entities.[2](https://github.com/search?l=Objective-C&q=xmpp&type=Repositories&utf8=%E2%9C%93) Originally named Jabber,[3] the protocol was developed by
>   the Jabber open-source community in 1999 for near real-time instant
>   messaging (IM), presence information, and contact list maintenance.
>   Designed to be extensible, the protocol has also been used for
>   publish-subscribe systems, signalling for VoIP, video, file transfer,
>   gaming, Internet of Things (IoT) applications such as the smart grid,
>   and social networking services.